# dialog box - how stay in the same line after executing a selection?

Tags: command-line

i am testing some things with a dialog box. when i execute for example a command via 3, and when its finished, it jumps back to position 1. i would like to have it, when i execute someting on 3, that after its finished, that it stays on 3 and when i execute it on 2, that it stay on 2 etc. how can i do it? thanx for the help in advance :)

this is a part of it:

```
DIALOG_CANCEL=1
DIALOG_ESC=255
HEIGHT=0
WIDTH=0

display_result() {
  dialog --title "$1" \
    --no-collapse \
    --msgbox "$result" 0 0
}

while true; do
  clear
  exec 3>&1
  selection=$(dialog \
    --backtitle "test" \
    --clear \
    --cancel-label "Exit" \
    --menu "Please select:" $HEIGHT $WIDTH 3 \
    "1" "test1" \
    "2" "test2" \
    "3" "test3" \
    2>&1 1>&3)
  exit_status=$?
  exec 3>&-
  case $exit_status in
    $DIALOG_CANCEL)
      clear
      tput cnorm
      exit
      ;;
    $DIALOG_ESC)
      clear
      tput cnorm
      exit
      ;;
    esac
  case $selection in
     1 )
      test1
      ;;
     2 )
      test2
      ;;
     3 )
      test3
      ;;
    esac
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have `dialog` remember the previous selection by saving it to a variable and restoring it to the `--default-item string` flag. Adding dividers is not supported, but you can add empty items.

```bash
DIALOG_CANCEL=1
DIALOG_ESC=255
HEIGHT=0
WIDTH=0
DEFAULT_ITEM=1

display_result() {
  dialog --title "$1" \
    --no-collapse \
    --msgbox "$result" 0 0
}

while true; do
  clear
  exec 3>&1
  selection=$(dialog \
    --backtitle "test" \
    --clear \
    --cancel-label "Exit" \
    --cr-wrap \
    --no-collapse \
    --default-item "$DEFAULT_ITEM" \
    --menu "Please select:" $HEIGHT $WIDTH 3 \
    "1" "test1" \
    "" "" \
    "2" "test2" \
    "" "" \
    "3" "test3" \
    2>&1 1>&3)
  exit_status=$?
  exec 3>&-
  case $exit_status in
    $DIALOG_CANCEL)
      clear
      tput cnorm
      exit
      ;;
    $DIALOG_ESC)
      clear
      tput cnorm
      exit
      ;;
    esac
  case $selection in
     1 )
      test1
      ;;
     2 )
      test2
      ;;
     3 )
      test3
      ;;
     * )
      continue
      ;;
  esac
  DEFAULT_ITEM="$selection"
done
```

Comment: thanx :) worked. one short question i have. how can i add an empy line for example between 1 and 2 or 2 and 3?
with this:


""  "" \


i have an empty line, but i can select it. is it possible to ignore the empty line, when i move up and down?

Comment: @gabberhead Both \\n, and an expanded \n in the text, as well as the `--no-collapse` and `--cr-wrap` options are ignored in menu items, suggesting that this is not supported. You could add dummy empty items as dividers, but it would be bad UX as dialog won't skip over them with the arrow keys

Comment: so its not possible to skip empty lines within the dialog menu?

Comment: @gabberhead No, this does not appear to be possible. I couldn't find anything in `man dialog` nor `/usr/share/doc/dialog/examples` . `--inputmenu` is the closest that is multiline but it draws a box instead of skipping lines, and seems to be for short answer

Comment: ok. thanx anyway. i will leave it like this: "" "" \

Comment: @gabberhead Ok, I added the empty items, as well as logic to not save the empty items as the default item. On AskUbuntu, instead of saying thanks, we usually click the "accept answer" checkmark if it works and you end up using this